# duplicate icons and probably duplicate application installations

Tags: thunderbird

After upgrading to 21.04, I now show two Firefox and two Thunderbird icons on my apps and it seems that I can't close Thunderbird even after closing out the window. When I use thunderbird, there is a dot when the app is open, and then there is a dot if I open an email (showing two dots). But now, with these duplicate icons (and likely duplicate apps) I cannot close thunderbird, and then I cannot open it once I close my open window. How do I remove the second install? When I go to Ubuntu apps, and click on the 'installed' list, nothing is coming up.

Comment: There appears to be a new bug in the latest TB. Log out, then log in, and retest. Are the duplicate icons on the Desktop? Report back.